# jQuery how to remove a class when another is removed? .on?

Tags: jquery

I need to remove a class when another is removed.

I was thinking something like this?? But I think it probably needs to contain the specific class that is being removed.

The class originally going to be removed is `.special`

```
$('#div1').on("removeClass", function(){
    $('#div1').removeClass('class-to-be-removed');
});
```

So something like on removal of `.special` also remove `.class-to-be-removed`

Can someone help me out on this one?

Comment: why can't you remove both classes at the same time?

Comment: It is controlled by some complicated JS from a plugin and it is triggered by multiple scenarios. I don't even understand half of it, unfortunately. This way would be faster and easier I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it.

You have to trigger `cssClassChanged` event during `addClass` of first one.
Then capture the event `cssClassChanged` to remove another class from the div.

Edit: As per me you are removing you class from a js. Trgiier removeClass event from there.
Like:

```
if(//some condition){
    $('#div1').addClass('special');
    $('#div1').trigger('addClass');
}
```

You need to capture the same:

```
$('#div1').bind('addClass', function() { 
  $('#div1').removeClass('class-to-be-removed');
);
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite following here